# Position a node in line does inside a xshift scope

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I would like to position a node at a certain position of a line I drawn.
Such line is drawn inside a scope environment with an `xshift`, that does not affect nodes!
A work around is to use the option `every node/.style={transform shape}` at the beginning of the picture, but then the font of the node is affected by the scaling of my various scope environments.

How can I use together `xshift, pos` for a node, without scaling the fonts?

Here my MWE

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={transform shape}]
 \begin{scope}[xshift=-5cm, scale = 0.1] %%Scale and move the picture
 \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) node (a)[pos=0.2]{$Hello World$}; %%Hello world now is tiny!
 \end{scope}
 ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: adding `transform shape=false` to the nodes that you don't want to transform?

Comment: That's not a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't shifted?

Comment: It is shifted if I use `transform shape` but then It will also be scaled. I want it to be shifted, but not scaled.

Comment: It is shifted without `transform shape`. You don't need `transform shape` to get it shifted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you think it isn't shifted? It certainly is, as the following example shows. `transform shape` is not needed for the shift at all.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle (1);
 \begin{scope}[xshift=-5cm, scale = 0.1] 
   \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) node (a)[pos=0.2]{$Hello World$}; 
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: shifted node]

The node is clearly shifted with the line to the left, in accordance with `xshift=-5cm`.